# How can I broadcast the Line-In from my sound card over LAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play audio over network with Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/29844/play-audio-over-network-with-windows-7)

I have a sound mixer which gives me an output. I plug it into the line-in of my sound card.

Am I able to broadcast it on the LAN, so I can hear the sound like radio from another computer in the same LAN?

Is there any free solution to do this, through software or a feature in Windows 7?

Comment: @techie007 I said line-in , not every sound , this app even stream windows error's sound which is not cool

Comment: There is more than one answer to that question (10), at least one includes VLC. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is able to do this.

You can look [here](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=85681) for details on setting up the stream in VLC to use the soundcard line input.