# Stream any audio (NOT FILES) from my PC to WDTV Live?

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, wdtv

I have a Windows 7 pc in a LAN which includes a WDTV Live. The pc is connected to the LAN via powerline, if that's of any significance. I'm currently using Serviio to stream files from my pc to the WDTV Live.

I would like to be able to stream whatever the sound card on the pc is playing (for instance, a playlist on my foobar2000, or streaming audio from soundcloud) to the WDTV device. Is there any way to send anything the soundcard is outputing to this media player?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using the sound controls in the control panel, there, in the playback options, the available devices should be listed, the WDTV should be listed there, just right click it and tick the 'use this device as the dafault...' and thus allowing the WDTV act as your speaker system on the TV

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, but the WDTV doesn't seem to be listed there. Any ideas? If it matters, the WDTV is on the LAN, not connected directly to the PC.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/29844/play-audio-over-network-with-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

You need a DLNA broadcast. I haved played files on my HTC Phone via WDTV Live device on the TV. 
Try these.

http://www.topnettricks.com/windows-8-dlna-media-server/

http://www.pcworld.com/article/245888/how_to_stream_digital_media_from_your_windows_7_pc.html

Comment: This seems to be about streaming media files to WDTV, not streaming whatever's on the sound card. Let me be clearer: I already know how to stream files to other devices on the network, I'm looking for a way to send over to the WDTV whatever's currently playing on my sound card. For example, I want to have a playlist playing on the pc, and send whatever the pc sound is outputting to the WDTV.